# React js App throwing cannot found @babel/preset-es2015

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have an app running on my windows system perfectly, but when I run it on Mac.

I am getting this error

[image]

I have already run this command `npm install` but not working

Comment: Do you have `@babel/preset-es2015` in your `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in `package.json`? If not, try `npm i -D @babel/preset-es2015` and then `npm install`

Comment: Yes, I have it...

Comment: do you have babel-core? one system might have it globally, another doesn't

Comment: Any updates on this, I am getting same thing. Well I haven't build solution for quite a while, tried it now and getting same thing without any changes in source